# Electron mirroring screen using using Airplay

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, airplay

I am working on Electron App for MacOS and I want to stream the MacOS Screen using Electron App I want to be able to :

1- Connect to the Airplay Device from the Electron App.

2- Mirror Screen to the Airplay Device from the Electron App.

3- Toggling between Mirror screen and using Airplay as extended 'Separate Screen' from the Electron App.

I tried this npm package [Airplay npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/airplay)  I was able to discover devices but not to connect and to mirror screen.